# Run-Time error '1004' with my VBA for hiding and unhiding rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have code for hiding and unhiding rows in my sheet based on changing the value in my dropdown.  Every time I change the dropdown I get Run-Time error of '1004'.  I had a private Sub before and changed it to a Sub but that doesn't seem to be the solution.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Target.Parent.Range("L6")

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.Run "dynamic_hide"

End Sub

Sub dynamic_hide()

If Target.Range = "$S$9:$S$51" Then

    If Target.Range = 0 Then Rows("F9:T51").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    If Target.Value <> 0 Then Rows("F9:T51").EntireRow.Hidden = False

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Target` variable is only declared in `Worksheet_Change` Sub, so the second Sub does not have access to it - you need to pass it as a parameter, or run all code inside one Sub. `If Target.Range = 0` - I think it should be Range.Value.

Comment: It almost looks like you could ignore Target and just test the value of cell L6 every time the worksheet is changed. If you keep a static copy of the value of L6 you can test independently whether there was actually a change.

Comment: Joffan the reason I included the target because L6 is a dropdown and I wanted to enact the event everytime I change the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems going on here:

First, the default property of a `Range` object is `Value`, so `Target.Range = "$S$9:$S$51"` will always be false.  Use `Target.Address` instead.

Second, don't use `Application.Run` to call `Subs` from the same `VBProject.`  Use `Call` instead.

Third, you've not let the sub `dynamic_hide` know what `Target` is since `Target` is only a parameter of the `Worksheet_Change` event subroutine.  You can solve this by declaring your sub like `Sub dynamic_hide(ByVal Target As Range)` And then you can use it: `Call dynamic_hide(Target)`

Lastly, since `Target` is a range you don't need to use `Target.Range` since `Target` is a range so you can simply omit every `.Range` from `Target.Range`  `Target.Parent.Range` is fine.